# Python Popen wait() returns 1 only when run from Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, popen

I've got a Python script that deals with some versions and runs a make file. If I run it from a cmd window it works fine, whereas if I run it from Jenkins wait() returns 1.

```
rslt = subprocess.Popen("build.bat", shell=True)

if rslt.wait() != 0:
  print "exiting " + str(rslt.wait())
  exit(1)
```

Any clues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the script is run in the same directory that contains `build.bat`.

By printing the return value of the [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd), you can check the directory where the script is run.

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

Comment: It is running in the same directory. Confirmed by getcwd(). It works if if run it from a command window but it does not from Jenkins.

Comment: @Oscar_Mariani, What's the content of the `build.bat`?

Comment: `@echo off 
@set TOOL_ROOT=C:/build_tools/.... 
@set path=%TOOL_ROOT%/bin 
echo. 
cd C:\someDIr\workspace 
make -f makeFile clean
`